# Cross-Database Joins

Tags: sql, join

I need to Join the following three different tables:
[image: Three tables with relationships]
*Note: Two different databases (Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kF87.png).*

How do I do the following:

1. Check if a persons has answer the question
2. Compare questions from table Outbox with answers from table Inbox

Comment: I suggest you do some reading up on [JOINS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php). Then write some SQL, show us, and let us help you if it is not working.

Comment: You need to also specify which database you are working with.  The syntax of join statements are not always the same between different databases.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this? 

 ** LEFT JOIN Server1.Database1.dbo.Inbox ON Outbox.Phonenumber = Inbox.Phonenumber **

Im executing the query on server2 in Database 2 where the table Outbox is.

Comment: You should specify if you are executing the query between 2 DATABASES or 2 SERVERS. The solution is much different between those 2 cases.

Answer (score 2):

There should be direct relationship between inbox and outbox table as a question can have many answers.

For your scenario try this- take the inner join between Database2.persons and database1.Inbox to find numbers of persons answered the questions-

**select p.id as personid, i.message, i.id as inboxid from database2.persons p join database1.inbox i on p.phonenumber = i.phonenumber;**

Next, Compare questions from table Outbox with answers from table Inbox-

**select i.personid, o.message as question, i.message as answer from 
(select p.id as personid, i.message from database2.person p join database1.inbox i on p.phonenumber = i.phonenumber) i join database2.outbox o on i.personid = o.personid;**